# return clean json Actionresult controller

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I have this acion

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Get(short Y, string r)
    {
        var items = await _tRepository.Get(Y, r);
        return Ok(items);
    }
```

the problem is that json i send to the client contains the parameter "items"

```
{"items":[{"k":9995,"y":"yyy"},{"Y":9934,"y":"xxx"}]}
```

i want to send the client clean json

Comment: What is **clean JSON**? What **exact** payload do you want to return?

Comment: Does `return Ok(items.items);` or `return Ok(items.Items);` do what you want?

Comment: The expectation is you will respond to comments.

Comment: i want : {[{"k":9995,"y":"yyy"},{"Y":9934,"y":"xxx"}]}
items.items wont compile

Comment: Please put a breakpoint on the `return` line. Run to it. When you hit the breakpoint, go to the `Immediate Window` and type in `?items` (enter). Please share the results from that call.

Answer (score -1):

It depend on your items type and if you need to return just array or list without items property, you must use  return Ok(items.Items);